# Perform an ANOVA for each individual level of a factor in R

Tags: r, split, anova

I am looking for a short and efficient method to run individual ANOVA analysis on each level of a factor. What I currently have, I think, is redundant and clutters the work space. Let's say I have the following:

```
Letter Number Question
A      1      1
A      2      1
A      3      1
B      1      1
B      2      1
B      3      1
C      1      1
C      2      1
C      3      1
```

I could run the following code to split the data frame into subsets A, B, and C:

```
> list2env(split(data, data$Letter), globalenv())
> ANOVA.A <- aov(Question~Number, data=A)
> ANOVA.B <- aov(Question~Number, data=B)
> ANOVA.C <- aov(Question~Number, data=C)
```

While this provides me with the required results, it clutters the workspace. My actual data set is far larger, so I am seeking something simpler and more elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using base `lapply`:

```
lapply(split(df, df$Letter), aov, formula=Question ~ Number)
```

Alternatively using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
obj <- df %>% group_by(Letter) %>% do(model = aov(Question~Number, data = .))
obj$model
```

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, list(Model = list(aov(Question ~ Number))), keyby = Letter]$Model
```

Comment: is it possible to perform a summary(aov) for each of the items?

Comment: Yes it is: just save, for example, the first alternative as `l` and then `lapply(l, summary)`