# split file ANOVA in r with result

Tags: r, split, lapply, anova

I am new to R and am trying to run a one-way ANOVA with split file option (similar to SPSS). The dataset file is called `rdatasetnew`. The three variables of interest are:

`orderNo`: the person identifier
`rating`: satisfaction rating for each order
`design`: website design used

The split file is done by `orderNo` as shown in the dataset below. I have used this Q&A to develop my split file syntax ([Perform an ANOVA for each individual level of a factor in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122162/perform-an-anova-for-each-individual-level-of-a-factor-in-r#))

The syntax I have developed looks as follows:

```
lapply(split(rdatasetnew, rdatasetnew$orderNo), aov, 
           formula = rating ~ design)
```

The above script offers sum of squares, degrees of freedom and residual standard error for each person. However, I want to get a summary table and mean data for each person. How can I do so?

```
orderNo rating  design
1123    1   Traditional Modern
1123    8   Traditional Modern
1123    1   Modern
1123    9   Modern
1123    8   Modern
1124    1   Modern
1124    10  Traditional Modern
1124    3   Traditional Modern
1124    10  Traditional
1124    8   Modern Extreme
1124    10  Traditional Modern
1168    6   Traditional Modern
1168    2   Traditional Modern
1168    10  Traditional Modern
1168    5   Modern
1168    8   Traditional Modern
1168    7   Traditional Modern
1168    2   Traditional Modern
```

Comment: You want mean data for each person, but of what variable? You can, for instance, do `lapply(split(etc), psych::describe)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas ... why does everyone forget `by` which replaces `split` + `lapply`: `by(rdatasetnew, rdatasetnew$orderNo,  psych::describe)`?

Comment: *I want to get a summary table and mean data for each person* ... summary table and mean of what? Please show desired output. Descriptive stats or regressions result stats?

Comment: @Parfait Maybe due to the format of the output?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I want the mean for the variable 'rating' for each person for each 'design' element.

Comment: @Parfait I tried the by function as you suggested but it does not allow ANOVA. Pardon me for my ignorance of R. Just started using it yesterday. As I tried to use below code it came up with an error. 

    by(rdatasetnew, rdatasetnew$customerName, aov, formula=rating ~ vesselTypes, psych::describe)

Comment: The function argument of `by` can be extended with an anonymous or named function: `by(rdatasetnew, rdatasetnew$customerName, function(sub) aov(formula=rating ~ vesselTypes, data=sub))`

Comment: @Parfait Thank you. However, this does not offer the mean for the rating variable as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr package is a great option here.

```
library(dplyr)
df1<- df %>%
group_by(orderNo) %>%
summarize(mean_rating = mean(rating), count = n())
```

The output takes the mean rating for each order number, and the total count.  You can also quickly make a table to group by design by replacing `orderNo` with `design`.

If you'd like to come up with means and counts for each order/design combination, this can be accomplished by adding more than one variable to the `group_by` statement, as follows

```
df1<- df %>%
group_by(orderNo, design) %>%
summarize(mean_rating = mean(rating), count = n())
```

This gives an output like:

```
orderNo design            mean_rating    count
1123    Modern             6.00           3
1123    Traditional Modern 4.50           2
1124    Modern             1.00           1
1124    Modern Extreme     8.00           1
```

Comment: The above gives me mean rating for each person but not for each person for each element of design.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've updated the answer to reflect this grouping structure.

Comment: This is really useful. The new table helps. Thank you.